# Code Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

The question is very simple, I hope someone knows the code that makes my case.

In fact, writing: `q1 /. {"q" <> ToString[1] -> 2}` I get `q1` instead of `2`.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There is a Mathematica SE.  Shouldn't this question be posted there?

Comment: Try [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this:

`q1 /. {ToExpression["q" <> "1"] -> 2}`

The thing your bit of code is doing is trying to find the string `q1` instead of the variable with the name `q1`.

---

Clarification:

When you just type the letters `q1` in Mathematica, it treats the thing like an expression or a single variable. That is, you can assign it a value such as in

`q1=2`

And this would make it treat all occurrences of `q1` as the number `2`. On the other hand, if you type `"q1"`, it thinks you are talking about a string whose content is the character pair `q1`. So your original code is something akin to:

`[expression] /. {[string] -> [value]}`

when what you want is

`[expression] /. {[expression] -> [value]}`

Thanks for posting this question. It gave me a reason to learn a little more about playing with Mathematica, and this may come in handy in future programming projects.

Comment: You can display text formatted as computer code by enclosing it between backticks "`".

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you. I will start doing that in the future.